# perfect scrollbar scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How i can use

```
perfectScrollbar('update');
```

with my this code in angular.js

```
$http.get('demo/json/test.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.items = data;
    })
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a modal or just show a model in a DIV.

```
 <div id="perfectView">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <p>{{item.name}}</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Then you can call your action;

```
$http.get('demo/json/test.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.items = data;
      //init perfectScroll
       $('#perfectView').perfectScrollbar();

    })
```

Comment: not worked. actually i want to show scroll bar on run time when i load my page. but it is showing when i scroll by mouse.